# Closeness of any matrix to a diagonalizable matrix in terms of norm-2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assuming $X \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, how to show that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exist a diagonalizable matrix $D \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ such that
$\left \| X-D \right \|_2 < \epsilon$?

(A given hint is to use Schur decomposition which estates that any $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ can be decomposed as $VUV^*$, where $V$ is unitary and $U$ is upper triangular.)

Comment: Just expanding slightly on Jonas Meyer's answer. From the hint, you see that it suffices to do it for upper-tirangular matrices. Now recall that the eigenvalues of such a matrix are the diagonal elements. Sufficient condition: if the eigenvalues are pairwise distinct, then the matrix is diagonalizable. So you just have to approximate your upper-triangular matrix by such matrices. For instance, if you add the diagonal matrix $(\epsilon,2\epsilon,\ldots,n\epsilon)$, you will eventually get such matrices.

Answer (score 3):

Using the hint, take $V$ unitary such that $U=V^*XV$ is upper triangular.  Let $B$ be an upper triangular matrix all of whose diagonal entries are distinct, such that the entries off the diagonal are the same as those of $U$, and $\|U-B\|_2<\varepsilon$.  Let $D=VBV^*$.